# How to print list by using format function

Tags: python, list, printing, format

I transfer form JAVA and pretty new in python.I knew python is a convenience language. Then I consider if or not a way I could use in print(''.format()) function to print a list, which I insert couple of word in between value.

I have already tried print(''.format(for i in list)) as simple example showed below:

```
movies.append(1)
movies.append('The Shawshank Redemption')
movies.append('5 star')
movies.append('whatever')
movies.append('www.google.com')
print('''
    The NO.{} Movie is :{}
    Rating:{}
    Quote:{}
    Link:{}
    '''.formate(for i in movie)
```

of course, it shows error invalid syntax at last statement.

Comment: A list is not the ideal data structure here, you would have better luck with a dictionary. 
    `movies = [{'title': 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'rating': '5 star', 'quote':'whatever', 'link': 'www.google.com'}]` 
You aren't using .format() correctly. It is for formating a single string with a list of input arguments. You could use it in a loop, but not as a loop.

Comment: `.format(*movie)`

Comment: The syntax error is that you are missing a closing parenthesis `)` (also `format` not `formate`)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Good call, forgot about the list unpacking operator. That would work well here.

Comment: @campellcl still good comment. You remind me to use the dictionary in this case.thx

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga such easy! it works. thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for i in movies` is a for statement, so it expects to have a block of code.

What you want is to get every item for item in movies, and then pass each item to the function, so you should do this instead

```py
print('''
    The NO.{} Movie is :{}
    Rating:{}
    Quote:{}
    Link:{}
    '''.format(*(i for i in movie)) # '*' unpacks the generator, so instead of passing a whole object to the function, you pass every object in the generator as an argument
```

Note that you can actually pass the unpacked list to `format` like so

```py
print('''
    The NO.{} Movie is :{}
    Rating:{}
    Quote:{}
    Link:{}
    '''.format(*movies) # '*' unpacks the generator, so instead of passing a whole object to the function, you pass every object in the generator as an argument
```

Answer (score 1):

`*movies` [unpack argument lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
movies = []
movies.append(1)
movies.append('The Shawshank Redemption')
movies.append('5 star')
movies.append('whatever')
movies.append('www.google.com')
print('The NO.{}\nMovie is :{}\nRating:{}\nQuote:{}\nLink:{} '.format(*movies))
```

Output is

```
The NO.1
Movie is :The Shawshank Redemption
Rating:5 star
Quote:whatever
Link:www.google.com
```

Comment: You are also right. But I can only accept one. :( Thx anyway